# laravel collective form database autoselect

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravelcollective

I have forms that will store some data in  DB, but next time when I open that page I want autoselected values selected already

```
{!! Form::select('week_starts', [
                                            'Monday' => 'Monday',
                                             'Tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
                                             'Wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
                                             'Thursday' => 'Thursday',
                                             'Friday' => 'Friday',
                                             'Saturday' => 'Saturday',
                                             'Sunday' => 'Sunday'
                                            ]) !!}
```

so I need form that will check from DB (that's not problem) and if found in database example Monday and Tuesday these fields will be autoselected with param selected=true

any idea how to do that.
I tried to `<?php if... ?>` but its not working inside {!! ... !!}

Answer (score 1):

You should pass and ID of selected option [as third parameter](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists):

```
{!! Form::select('week_starts', [
    'Monday' => 'Monday',
    Tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
    Wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
    Thursday' => 'Thursday',
    Friday' => 'Friday',
    Saturday' => 'Saturday',
    Sunday' => 'Sunday'
], 'Friday') !!}
```

You should get this data from DB in controller or a model and pass as variable into the view.

Or you could use [`Form::model`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding) binding, in this case ID will be set automatically.

Comment: nice, this will work for dropdown, any idea how to pass true/false on checkbox?

Comment: For checkbox you [should pass `true` as third parameter](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons) to make the checkbox to be checked.